# Running a SQL delete query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an SQL query:

```
DELETE n1 
  FROM satellites n1
     , satellites n2 
 WHERE n1.id < n2.id 
   AND n1.norad_cat_id = n2.norad_cat_id
```

What this query does is delete rows that have the same `norad_cat_id` and only leave one with the highest `id`. I don't know if my SQL query is correct, but I will have to see.

I am a bit stuck when it comes to running raw SQL queries in Laravel. From this documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries) you can see that you have a few options to run the query:

`DB::update('SQL QUERY HERE');`

`DB::delete('SQL QUERY HERE');`

`DB::statement('SQL QUERY HERE');`

`DB::select( DB::raw('SQL QUERY HERE'));`

In my case I am trying to delete duplicate rows while only leaving the one with the highest `id`. What Laravel `DB` statement do I run to achieve the results I want or does it matter at all?

**EDIT:** SQL query for @MasudMiah

`delete satellites
   from satellites
  inner join (
     select max(id) as lastId, norad_cat_id
       from satellites
      group by norad_cat_id
     having count(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.norad_cat_id = satellites.norad_cat_id
  where satellites.norad_cat_id < duplic.lastId;`

Comment: (collected)
$deleteDuplicates = DB::table('questions as n1')
                    ->join('questions as n2', 'n1.id', '>', 'n2.id')
                    ->where('n1.name', '=', 'n2.name')
                    ->delete();

The query might look like this:

DELETE n1 FROM questions n1, questions n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name

Comment: @MasudMiah That did not work - no error warnings or anything.

Comment: brother, what query you executed can you show me?

Comment: @MasudMiah The SQL query I posted above works, but it deletes all the rows that have the same `norad_cat_id`. I need one left that has highest `id`

Comment: can you change this line 
 where satellites.norad_cat_id < duplic.lastId;
to this  where satellites.norad_cat_id > duplic.lastId;
i am not sure though

Comment: @MasudMiah Tried that - adding that stops it deleting the rows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to run directly your DELETE SQL query, you can use:

```
$nrd = DB::delete('SQL QUERY HERE');
```

It returns the number of affected /deleted rows.
See this page:

http://coursesweb.net/laravel/working-mysql-database#anc_rsq

Comment: Try this sql: `DELETE FROM satellites WHERE norad_cat_id NOT IN
 (SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT MAX(n.norad_cat_id) FROM satellites n
   GROUP BY n.norad_cat_id) x
 )`

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. There is no error code. It just freezes.

Comment: I tested the following query, and it worked. Try test it in PhpMyAdmin: `DELETE FROM satellites WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(n.id) FROM satellites n GROUP BY n.norad_cat_id) x)`

Comment: It works! Just tested it and confirm that it does what I want it  to do! I just need to put it into a `DB` statement.

Answer (score 11):

I am afraid your query is not right though. but let me show you some :

```
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE user_id='$your_provided_value';
    DELETE FROM table2 WHERE user_id='$your_provided_value';
```

Now using query builder for laravel :

```
DB::table('table_name')
->where('id',$your_provided_value)
->delete();
```

One thing I would like to mention to set multiple conditions like id = 1 AND gender = 'male' you need to something like that

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id',1)
->where('gendar','male')
->delete();
```

Now by eloquent :

```
User:where('id', 1)->delete();
```

here User is your model for the users table. Hope you are getting some basics.
by visiting below link you get the idea of using eloquent.
    https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

Comment: I was trying to make a query which was unsuccessful. Since my database updates I would need it to remove all duplicates. Your code needs `$your_provided_value` - which in my case I cannot get since it needs to be dynamic. Please see my updated query. The updated query is able to delete all for the rows with the same `norad_cat_id`, but I need one left.